# Merge nodes with "Batch Importer" or with neo4j 2.2 ImportTool

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, data-import

Can I use MERGE when import data using [Batch Importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) or [neo4j 2.2 ImportTool](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/import-tool.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't both tools are only for inserting data.

You would have to clean your CSV first.

Or you could use a custom importer that handles it more gracefully.

see: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/flexible-neo4j-batch-import-with-groovy/